# Node module issues when gradually upgrading to React 17 from React 15

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5

I've run into a weird issue when trying to gradually upgrade. If you don't know, React Gradual upgrade is a fun process where you require three package.json's - one in the root directory, one in src/legacy and one in src/modern. Refer to here for more info: [GitHub](https://github.com/reactjs/react-gradual-upgrade-demo) I am getting the errors after running npm start ("webpack-dev-server --hot"):

```
ERROR in ./src/client/app/legacy/node_modules/radium/lib/index.js 22:24-63
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../ProofEdit/CampusProofCard' in 'C:\Users\wicra\OneDrive\Desktop\Code2\TgccWeb\src\client\app\legacy\node_modules\radium\lib'
 @ ./src/client/app/legacy/tgccmain.tsx 33:15-32

ERROR in ./src/client/app/legacy/node_modules/react-bootstrap/es/index.js 22:24-63
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../ProofEdit/CampusProofCard' in 'C:\Users\wicra\OneDrive\Desktop\Code2\TgccWeb\src\client\app\legacy\node_modules\react-bootstrap\es'
 @ ./src/client/app/legacy/RealCampus/RealCampusDesignListView.tsx 33:24-50
 @ ./src/client/app/legacy/tgccmain.tsx 114:33-81

ERROR in ./src/client/app/legacy/node_modules/react-dom/index.js 22:24-63
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../ProofEdit/CampusProofCard' in 'C:\Users\wicra\OneDrive\Desktop\Code2\TgccWeb\src\client\app\legacy\node_modules\react-dom'
 @ ./src/client/app/legacy/tgccmain.tsx 20:15-35

ERROR in ./src/client/app/legacy/node_modules/react-redux/lib/index.js 22:24-63
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../ProofEdit/CampusProofCard' in 'C:\Users\wicra\OneDrive\Desktop\Code2\TgccWeb\src\client\app\legacy\node_modules\react-redux\lib'
 @ ./src/client/app/legacy/tgccmain.tsx 24:20-42 25:20-42

ERROR in ./src/client/app/legacy/node_modules/react-router/es/index.js 22:24-63
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../ProofEdit/CampusProofCard' in 'C:\Users\wicra\OneDrive\Desktop\Code2\TgccWeb\src\client\app\legacy\node_modules\react-router\es'
 @ ./src/client/app/legacy/tgccmain.tsx 22:21-44 26:21-44

ERROR in ./src/client/app/legacy/node_modules/react/react.js 22:24-63
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../ProofEdit/CampusProofCard' in 'C:\Users\wicra\OneDrive\Desktop\Code2\TgccWeb\src\client\app\legacy\node_modules\react'
 @ ./src/client/app/legacy/tgccmain.tsx 19:12-28

ERROR in ./src/client/app/modern/node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-react.browser.esm.js 22:24-63
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../ProofEdit/CampusProofCard' in 'C:\Users\wicra\OneDrive\Desktop\Code2\TgccWeb\src\client\app\modern\node_modules\@emotion\react\dist'
 @ ./src/client/app/modern/HomePage/SplashPage.tsx 20:14-39
 @ ./src/client/app/legacy/tgccmain.tsx 70:19-59

ERROR in ./src/client/app/modern/node_modules/@emotion/react/jsx-runtime/dist/emotion-react-jsx-runtime.browser.esm.js 22:24-63
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../ProofEdit/CampusProofCard' in 'C:\Users\wicra\OneDrive\Desktop\Code2\TgccWeb\src\client\app\modern\node_modules\@emotion\react\jsx-runtime\dist'
 @ ./src/client/app/modern/HomePage/SplashPage.tsx 18:20-57
 @ ./src/client/app/legacy/tgccmain.tsx 70:19-59

ERROR in ./src/client/app/modern/node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js 22:24-63
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../ProofEdit/CampusProofCard' in 'C:\Users\wicra\OneDrive\Desktop\Code2\TgccWeb\src\client\app\modern\node_modules\react-redux\es'
 @ ./src/client/app/modern/node_modules/react/index.js 21:20-42
 @ ./src/client/app/modern/HomePage/SplashPage.tsx 21:12-28
 @ ./src/client/app/legacy/tgccmain.tsx 70:19-59

ERROR in ./src/client/app/modern/node_modules/react-router-dom/esm/react-router-dom.js 22:24-63
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../ProofEdit/CampusProofCard' in 'C:\Users\wicra\OneDrive\Desktop\Code2\TgccWeb\src\client\app\modern\node_modules\react-router-dom\esm'
 @ ./src/client/app/modern/HomePage/SplashPage.tsx 23:25-52
 @ ./src/client/app/legacy/tgccmain.tsx 70:19-59

ERROR in ./src/client/app/modern/node_modules/react/index.js 22:24-63
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../ProofEdit/CampusProofCard' in 'C:\Users\wicra\OneDrive\Desktop\Code2\TgccWeb\src\client\app\modern\node_modules\react'
 @ ./src/client/app/modern/HomePage/SplashPage.tsx 21:12-28
 @ ./src/client/app/legacy/tgccmain.tsx 70:19-59
```

Initially, before I added the modern folder, just to get it to build I added the packages that were causing the errors into the root package.json and that fixed the issue. However, it should be reading the package.json directly from the respective folder. I tried to do the same work around for React 17 dependencies (ex. Emotion 11), but it gave a mismatched React version error since I'm not actually supposed to have any version of React in my root directory, just in legacy and modern. I can fully confirm the file it keeps referencing is present ('../ProofEdit/CampusProofCard'). It's just strange that it keeps referencing that particular file. Side note, I am also using aliases in my typescript config/webpack config. Also, most of my npm packages have been manually added to my package.json files, not using npm install "package_name".

I am honestly stuck and would love to answer any questions about how I can help you help me. You guys are the best!